# Разные результаты при использовании tuple и np.array в функции minimize библиотеки scipy.optimize

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект, scipy

Выполняю минимизацию функции, и при использовании данных в формате tuple, и все корректно работает, но очень долго. Хотел оптимизировать код, перевел все на np.array, но теперь получаются другие значения, меня они не удовлетворяют, но по скорости все отлично. Помогите разобраться, что необходимо сделать что бы получить скорость как с np.array, но данные что бы были как с tuple.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import time
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)

start_time = time.time()

def Bass1(x, P, Q, M):
    return (P*M+(Q-P)*(x))-(Q/M)*(x**2)

def squareMistake1(k: tuple, *sales) -> float:
    p0 = 0
    c0 = sales[0]
    res = 0  # Значение функции
    for i in range(1, len(sales)):
        p = Bass1(c0, P=k[0], Q=k[1], M=k[2])
        c = c0 + p
        res += (c - sales[i])**2
        p0 = p
        c0 = c
    return res


# Готовим данные для минимизации
# Начальные значения параметров
k0 = [0.0008791696672306727, 0.19252826585535315, 3328.9193848309856]
# Все параметры неотрицательные
kb = ((0, None), (0, None), (0, None))

# тот набор данных который необходим, идеальные значения, большое время исполнения
generate = tuple([8.26192344363636, 9.20460066059596, 12.0178164697778, 15.921260267805, 21.2161740066094, 31.420434564131, 38.3904519471421, 52.3307819867071, 62.9113953016839, 85.1161924282732, 104.083879757882, 132.859216030029, 170.682620580279, 220.600045153997, 276.020526299077, 346.465021938078, 440.385091980306, 530.55442135112, 635.49205101167, 705.805860788812, 831.42968828187, 962.227395409379, 1140.31094904253, 1269.52053571083, 1418.17004626655, 1591.2135122193])
# аналогичный набор данных, значения не устраивают, малое время исполнения
# generate = np.array([8.26192344363636, 9.20460066059596, 12.0178164697778, 15.921260267805, 21.2161740066094, 31.420434564131, 38.3904519471421, 52.3307819867071, 62.9113953016839, 85.1161924282732, 104.083879757882, 132.859216030029, 170.682620580279, 220.600045153997, 276.020526299077, 346.465021938078, 440.385091980306, 530.55442135112, 635.49205101167, 705.805860788812, 831.42968828187, 962.227395409379, 1140.31094904253, 1269.52053571083, 1418.17004626655, 1591.2135122193])

# список методов используемый в минимизации
metod_list = ['Nelder-Mead', 'Powell', 'L-BFGS-B', 'TNC', 'SLSQP', 'trust-constr']

for i in metod_list:
    # Минимизируем сумму квадратов
    try:
        res = minimize(squareMistake1, k0, args=generate, method=i, bounds=kb)
    except:
        print(f'Минимизация методом {i} не удалась!')
    k = tuple(res.x)  # Получаем кортеж параметров
    print(f'k = {k}')

end_time = time.time()
total_time = end_time - start_time
print(f'Время выполнения: {total_time} seconds')
```

Comment: А какие значения являются удовлетворительными?

Comment: Для меня лучшее значение  k = tuple(res.x) при generate = tuple..., то что получается при generate = np.array..., неудовлетворительно. В моем случает очень долго выполняется метод trust-constr, почему то на нём очень сильно тормозится, выполнение 1.4 секунды.

Comment: У меня нет возможности запустить ваш код, поэтому я не знаю, какие значения вы ожидаете в `k = tuple(res.x)`. Будет лучше, если вы покажите эти значения.
Есть ещё один большой вопрос. Зачем использовать всевозможные методы для решения данной задачи? Ведь в ней нет ничего особенного. И неудивительно, что trust-constr выполняется долго - он заточен под решение задач в других постановках и "под капотом" выполняет множество бессмысленных операций для рассматриваемой задачи.

Comment: minimize также способна сама подобрать метод, исходя из заданных параметров. И делает это неплохо.

Comment: В функции `squareMistake1`  у вас есть неиспользуемая переменная `p0`. Такое обычно наталкивает на мысли об ошибочности алгоритма.
Также непонятно, зачем вы замеряете время всего скрипта, но при этом судите о скорости отдельных методов.